# How to define apostrophe as thousand separator character in OFC2?

Tags: formatting, decimal-point, open-flash-chart, openflashchart2

I would like to separate numbers with more then 3 digits with another character then a comma or a dot in Open Flash Chart 2.

In my region/country we format a big amount like this: 1'234'567.95

I only found the way to choose between a comma or a dot as a thousand separator here:
http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/doxygen/html/classopen__flash__chart.html

How can I define the apostrophe character ' as number format separator like in #'###.00